# 01031. 00000 - "insufficient privileges" while granting System Privileges to the new user

Tags: oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, ora-00942, ora-01031

I created a new connection in Oracle SQL Developer. Under this new connection, I created a new user. Now, I'm trying to grant roles and System privileges to this new user. I get the following error while trying to grant system privileges to the new user:

[image]

The new user has been granted all the roles successfully. However, I'm unable to grant all system privileges to it.

**UPDATE:**

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P7f_fmH-Deg) and [this](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-create-a-user-and-grant-permissions-in-oracle/) links to grant sysdba privilege to the new user using the command prompt. I'm able to grant sysdba to this new user. However, when I try to grant all system privileges from the Oracle sql Developer, I get the same error (specified in the screenshot above). I am trying to grant all the system privilege to the new user because I'm getting following error while trying to access the tables of the database.[image]

Recently I had to change my OS to Windows 10. Earlier I had Windows 7 and I didn't have any of this issues. Is this issue related to OS? Is there any problem to use Oracle SQL Developer in Windows 10?

Comment: ORA-00942: table or view doesn't exist. It is, I'd say, not related to SYSDBA, but the fact that table you used in a query isn't accessible to you. The owner should grant (at least) SELECT to you, while you need to precede table name with owner name, or create a synonym, or use a public synonym. Does this help?

Comment: I follow [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58V-w3buWm4] to create a new connection and new user in Oracle SQL developer. In Windows 7, there was not any problem at all. I'm facing it in Windows 10. Moreover, this link [http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01031_insufficient_privileges.htm] talks about the problems at the operating system level. However, I could not solve the issue with the solution explained in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this [blog](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01031_insufficient_privileges.htm)

> The ORA-01031: "insufficient privileges" error occurs when you attempt
>   to execute a program or function for which you have not been granted
>   the appropriate privileges.
>
> For the DBA, the ORA-01031 can happen if the target OS executables do
>   not have read and execute permissions (e.g. (770) in UNIX/Linux), and
>   ensure that the oracle user is a member of the dba group (e.g.
>   /etc/group).  There are similar permission in the Windows registry.
>
> Inside Oracle, the "ORA-01031: insufficient privileges" error can be
>   avoided by signing on "as sysdba" with unlimited database privileges.
>
> The oerr utility notes this on the ORA-01031 error:
>
> **ORA-01031: insufficient privileges**
>
> **Cause**: An attempt was made to change the current username or password
>   without the appropriate privilege. This error also occurs if
>   attempting to install a database without the necessary operating
>   system privileges. When Trusted Oracle is configure in DBMS MAC, this
>   error may occur if the user was granted the necessary privilege at a
>   higher label than the current login.
>
> **Action**: Ask the database administrator to perform the operation or
>   grant the required privileges. For Trusted Oracle users getting this
>   error although granted the appropriate privilege at a higher label,
>   ask the database administrator to re-grant the privilege at the
>   appropriate label.

Answer (score 1):

You should be connected as SYS or SYSTEM in order to grant SYSDBA. Are you?

For example:

```
connect sys/pwd@db as sysdba
grant sysdba to santobedi;
```

Comment: I did it, however, the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1):

Connect as sysdba

```
bash-4.2$ $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus / as sysdba
```

show user will show user as 'SYS'
show con_name will display CDB$ROOT

```
SQL> alter session set container=PDB19;

Session altered.

SQL> grant sysdba to ggadmin;

Grant succeeded.
```